# Caret does not find method

Tags: r, r-caret

I installed the caret package with the command line:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

... which should install all necessary packages.

I also installed kernlab and e1071 additionally.

Still I get the error message: "Model svmlinear is not in caret's built-in library". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It was just a typo. I used "svmlinear" instead of "svmLinear".

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "LiblineaR" package.